# How to use query from postgres properly in a Java JPA repository?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have this query :

```
SELECT * FROM public.app_catalog as a , (SELECT  app_id , COUNT(*) as count 
FROM public.statistics_log 
where logged_at between  '2019-08-20 12:22:40.186'   and '2019-08-22 12:22:40.186'           
GROUP BY app_id
LIMIT 10) AS App_id 
where App_id.app_id = a.app_catalog_id
```

And I want to write this in a Java repository

I tried like this:

```
/**
 * @param startDate .
  * @param enddate .
 * @return AppCatalog
 */
@Query("SELECT app FROM "
        + "(SELECT  b.app_id , COUNT(*) as count"
        + "FROM public.statistics_log as b inner join public.app_catalog as app on  b.app_id = app.app_catalog_id"
        + "where b.logged_at between :startDate and :endDate "
        + "GROUP BY b.app_id"
        + "LIMIT 10)app")
List<AppCatalog> findingTrendingAppsInCatalog(@Param("startDate") LocalDate startDate,
                                              @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime enddate);
```

The error I am getting:

> Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.xitee.cbc.repository.AppCatalogRepository.findingTrendingAppsInCatalog(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDateTime)!

But it seems the syntax is wrong because it does not compile.

Comment: It might help to include the error messages you get in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the outer select and you need to leave spaces between the strings that you concatenate:

```
@Query("SELECT  b.app_id, COUNT(*) as count "
     + "FROM public.statistics_log as b inner join public.app_catalog as app "           
     + "ON b.app_id = app.app_catalog_id "
     + "WHERE b.logged_at BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate "
     + "GROUP BY b.app_id "
     + "LIMIT 10")
```

Comment: Does this select all the column in app_catalog

Comment: It selects: `app_id` and `count` just like the query you wrote, because `select * from (...)` selected 2 columns.

Comment: I want to select all the column in app catalog, is that possible

Comment: This answer is about the syntax error you get. If you solved this and you have another requirement post a new question describing what you want.

Comment: Hi, I just edit my SQL query, can you have a look, please?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in your question because you invalidate the existing answer(s).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198304/discussion-between-ilia-tapia-and-forpas).